# How to nicely transform a Try[Unit] to a Unit while handling certain exceptions?

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

I have something like this:

```
def mySideEffectingMethod(): Unit = {
  Try(someSideEffectingJavaMethod()) match {
    case Failure(_: SomeExpectedException) => someSideEffectingJavaMethod() //perhaps attempt it again, for example
    case Failure(ex) => throw ex
    case Success(_) => //unit
  }
}
```

Is there a way in which I could lose the ugly `case Success(_) => //unit`? I don't think `recover` and `recoverWith` will cut it because they will in this case return `Try[Unit]` instead of `Unit` thus suppressing the non-expected exceptions.

Comment: Sorry, but in this case I think you need a `try` statement and not a `Try` monad. You use `Try` if you want to accumulate errors in a functional fashion and apply some other function to objects that belongs to `Success[T]`.

Comment: Yep, okay that's fair enough. I suppose the ugliness above works as well.

Comment: If you really do not care about the value the Success try carries why not just default? `case _ =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `Try[T]` monad when you want to treat exceptions and errors in a *functional* way. In particular, using the `Try[T]` monad lets you to accumulate exception and continue to elaborate results that belongs to `Success[T]`, which is a subclass of `Try[T]`.

It seems that in your case you need only to treat exceptional behaviour. In this case you can simply use the `try` statement.

```
def mySideEffectingMethod = {
   try {
     someSideEffectingJavaMethod 
   } catch {
     case _: SomeExpectedException => someSideEffectingJavaMethod()    
     //perhaps attempt it again, for example
     case ex => throw ex
   }
}
```

In you case, you can use the `try` statement because you're doing some *side effects* on inputs. But, if you adopt a more *functional* approach, which means no side effects at all, you have to revamp the `Try` monad.

I think that one of the best guides that explains how to treat exceptions in a functional way in Scala is [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 6: Error Handling With Try](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using the `Try` type:

```
def mySideEffectingMethod(): Unit = {
  Try(someSideEffectingJavaMethod()).failed.foreach {
    case _: SomeExpectedException => 
      //perhaps attempt it again, for example
      someSideEffectingJavaMethod() 
    case ex => throw ex
  }
}
```